# C++ lib RTTI in C# application

Tags: c#, c++, rtti

I am developing game editor in C# that uses c++ lib files.
I want RTTI for C++ classes in C#.
Is it possible to get RTTI of C++ class in C#?
If yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not expose native C++ types or code directly to the .NET platform.

There are however three ways of interacting with "native" C & C++ code from .NET (in C#, VB.Net or whatever).

1. COM
2. P/Invoke
3. CLI/C++

COM is probably the easiest to use from the .NET side.  Just add the COM object to your .NET project as a reference and start interacting with the interfaces and classes.  For more detail on interactive with COM in .NET have a read of a book like this:

[image: .NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide]

[http://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232170X)

This of course requires you to expose your game engine objects as COM objects.  This is non-trivial.

The next easiest to use is P/Invoke.  If your game code is packaged in a standard windows DLL with a C calling convention you can access functions in that DLL using P/Invoke.  For example:

```
public static class UserDll
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FlashWindow(IntPtr hwnd, bool bInvert);

    public static void FlashWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Form window)
    {
        FlashWindow(window.Handle, false);
    }
}
```

You can do a lot with P/Invoke.  Even have your C/C++ code call back into C# with delegates and what not.

I've built game engine tools in the past that used P/Invoke to call out to functions exposed in a DLL.  You just have to be careful about the management of native resources.  Here the IDisposable interface and class finalizers become your friends. Eg:

```
public class Player : IDisposable
{
    private IntPtr _thePlayer;

    public Player()
    {
        _thePlayer = CreatePlayer();
    }

    ~Player()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
           // dispose of managed objects (ie, not native resources only)
        }

        if (_thePlayer != IntPtr.Empty)
        {
            DestroyPlayer(_thePlayer);
            _thePlayer = IntPtr.Empty;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("gameengine.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreatePlayer();

    [DllImport("gameengine.dll")]
    private static extern void DestroyPlayer(IntPtr player);
}
```

There is a downside to using P/Invoke.  First it can add a significant marshalling overhead to native calls (though there are ways of speeding that up).  It also requires a C API in the gameengine.dll.  If your engine is C++ classes you have to provide a C API to the C++ classes.  This can add a whole lot of work (or require a code generator).

I'm not going to go into any more detail on all the messy details of dealing with Marshalling managed objects/data to and from native code.  Just know that it can be done and that MSDN is your friend here.

The third and probably best way of exposing native C++ code to .NET is via CLI/C++ mixed mode assemblies.  CLI/C++ lets you mix native and managed code together in a single assembly fairly seamlessly.

CLI/C++ has a funny syntax but if you're a C++ programmer it is not hard to adapt. An example might be something like this:

```
using namespace System;

// CLI/C++ "managed" interface 
interface class IDog
{
    void Bark();
};

#pragma managed(push off)

// Native C++
class Pet
{
public:
   Pet() {}
   ~Pet() {}

   const char* GetNativeTypeName()
   {
       return typeid(Pet).name();
   }
};

#pragma managed(pop)

// CLI/C++ "managed" class
ref class Dog : IDog
{
private:
    Pet* _nativePet;

public:
    Dog()
      : _nativePet(new Pet())
    {}
    ~Dog()
    {
        delete _nativePet; 
        _nativePet = 0;
    }

    void Bark()
    {
        // Managed code talking to native code, cats & dogs living together, oh my!
        Console::WriteLine("Bow wow wow!");

        Console::WriteLine(new System::String(_nativePet->GetNativeTypeName()));
    }
};

void _tmain()
{
    Dog^ d = gcnew Dog();
    d->Bark();
}
```

My recommendation (having done exactly what you're trying to do) is that for anything more than moderately complex, the best solution is to try and provide a CLI/C++ API to your game engine.  I learnt everything I needed to know about CLI/C++ off MSDN but I hear this book is good if you like meaty tomes.

[image: Expert Visual C++/CLI: .NET for Visual C++ Programmers]

[http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Visual-CLI-Programmers-Experts/dp/1590597567](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597567)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/131-Runtime-Type-Identification-R-T-T-I.aspx) describes the process.

> Runtime Type Identification(RTTI) allows the type of an object to be determined during program execution. C# includes three keywords that support runtime type identification: is, as and typeof.

You use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=VS.71).aspx) to determine whether an object is of the type you want:

```
if (myVariable is string)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

You use [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=VS.71).aspx) to convert from one object to another. If no conversion exists then `null` is returned.

```
string myString = myVariable as string;
if (myString != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

You use [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(VS.71).aspx) to obtain information about a type.

> To obtain the run-time type of an expression, you can use the .NET Framework method [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But you didn't get my question.
I want C++ lib file class RTTI which I am going to import in C#.

Comment: @Rushi - sorry, it wasn't clear from your question. Perhaps you should include an example of what you want to achieve.